# Load data to a table

Tags: java, mysql

```
  private void update_table(){
        try{
        DefaultTableModel df=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        Conn c=new Conn();
            Statement s=c.createConn().createStatement();
            //  df.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
            String sql="Select * from leave_taken";
            ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()){
                Vector v=new Vector();
                df.addRow(v);
                jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is what i wrote. i want to lad data to the table by this method. but it loads only the table headings. how can i load table data to the table? Is there some thing need to add to this code?

Answer (score 0):

Your **v** variable happens to be empty vector when you do `df.addRow(v)`. Seems like you don't need df in your code.

Full example working with data

[image]

```
package javaapplication2;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

public class JavaApplication2
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                JPanel p = new JPanel();
                f.setContentPane(p);
                f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                final JTable t = new JTable();
                p.add(new JScrollPane(t), BorderLayout.CENTER);

                JButton b = new JButton("Run");
                p.add(b, BorderLayout.WEST);
                b.addActionListener(
                    new ActionListener()
                    { 
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                                Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true;databaseName=stackoverflow");
                                Statement s  = c.createStatement();
                                ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM leave_taken");
                                t.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                            }
                            catch (SQLException es)
                            {
                                es.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            catch (ClassNotFoundException ecn)
                            {
                                ecn.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            } 
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Result on application start.

[image]

Result after button "Run" pressed.

[image]

Comment: import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

Comment: Try this: look at the example (above) of fireTableChanged usage and do the same for your code. What's the result for you? Does your table contain data?

Comment: You don't need the fireTableChanged((..) It is the job of the TableModel to invoke that method. All that is needed is: `t.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs))`